# describing proj. seurface.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I have the surface

$W=Z(x_0x_1-x_2x_3)$, in $\mathbb{P^3}$

and I want to describe it as a union of an affine piece and some other piece laying in $\mathbb{P^2}$.
My solution is to look at:

1-$W\cap D(x_0)$

2-$W\cap Z(x_0)$

regrading (1) I have its the surface laying in $\mathbb{A^3}$ giving by zero loci of $f=x-yz$
regrading (2) the intersection contains three points
$(0:1:0:0),(0:0:1:0),(0:0:0:1),(0:1:0:1),(0:1:1:0)$
now can I conclude that the second piece is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P^2}$?

Comment: Your surface $W$ is a smooth quadric and its tangent plane at $(0:1:0:0)$ is the plane at infinity $x_0=0$. That plane cuts the quadric $W$ in two lines (as does every tangent plane to $W$):  $x_0=x_2=0$ and $x_0=x_3=0$, and the union of these lines (a degenerate plane conic) is the projective piece $W\cap Z(x_0)$ you are looking for. (This is just a little geometric interpretation of Daniel's perfect answer).

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W \cap Z(x_0)$ is the intersection of two surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^3$, so it should be a curve.  In particular, we're looking at points $[0:x_1:x_2:x_3]$ such that $x_2 x_3 = 0$.  Of course this implies either $x_2 = 0$ or $x_3 = 0$, so we're looking at the union of the two lines $[0:\ast:0:\ast]$ and $[0:\ast:\ast:0]$.